get cast error for Generic type in xcode 16 for swift 6
I got a build error for below code after using xcode 16
Cast from 'ObservableCollection<E>.SectionsChange' (aka 'CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<E>>') to unrelated type 'ObservableCollection<Int>.SectionsChange' (aka 'CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<Int>>') always fails

for the section protocol method I implemented, first cast is still working
class ObservableCollectionDelegateMock: ObservableCollectionDelegate {

    var collectionDidRowBatchUpdateAtExpect = LIExpect()
    var collectionDidSectionBatchUpdateAtExpect = LIExpect()
    var rowBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Int>.RowsChange?
    var sectionBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Int>.SectionsChange?

    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.RowsChange) {
        collectionDidRowBatchUpdateAtExpect.called(actualParams: nil)
        rowBatchUpdates = change as? ObservableCollection<Int>.RowsChange
    }

    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.SectionsChange) {
        collectionDidSectionBatchUpdateAtExpect.called(actualParams: nil)
        sectionBatchUpdates = change as? ObservableCollection<Int>.SectionsChange
    }
}

Here is the definition of the ObservableCollectionDelegate
which is the protocol delcare these 2 methods, that sublass to override
public protocol ObservableCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {

    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.RowsChange)
    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.SectionsChange)
}


here is the definition of the these 2 alias.

 class ObservableCollection<Element> {

    // MARK: - Nested Types

    public typealias RowsChange = CollectionChange<IndexPath, Element>
    public typealias SectionsChange = CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<Element>>

     .......
 }


and this is the define of ObservableArray
public class ObservableArray<T> {

    // MARK: - Public Properties

    public var count: Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return elements.isEmpty
    }
    public var hasElements: Bool {
        return !elements.isEmpty
    }

    /// Returns the snapshot of current state as a normal array. (Essentially returning the copy of itself).
    public var snapshot: [T] {
        return elements
    }

    // MARK: - Internal Properties

    internal(set) public var elements: [T]

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    public init<S>(elements: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == T {
        self.elements = [T](elements)
    }
    
    ......


From what I am understanding, seems for xcode 16, then can't case the generic type by compiler if there are nested generic types.
which is our case is
ObservableCollection.SectionsChange' (aka 'CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray>')
wonder if there is anyway to go around this? or this is what swift 6 forbid to do?
thanks
====================================================
To make the code more easy to reproduce, I create a demo to have the same issue
import UIKit
import Foundation

public struct CollectionChange<Index: Hashable, Value> {}
public class ObservableArray<T> {


    // MARK: - Internal Properties

    internal(set) public var elements: [T]

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    public init<S>(elements: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == T {
        self.elements = [T](elements)
    }

    public convenience init() {
        self.init(elements: [])
    }
}

open class ObservableCollection<Element> {

    public typealias RowsChange = CollectionChange<IndexPath, Element>
    public typealias SectionsChange = CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<Element>>
}

public protocol ObservableCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {

    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.RowsChange)
    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.SectionsChange)
}


class ObservableCollectionDelegateMock: ObservableCollectionDelegate {

    var rowBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Int>.RowsChange?
    var sectionBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Int>.SectionsChange?

    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.RowsChange) {
        rowBatchUpdates = change as? ObservableCollection<Int>.RowsChange
    }

    func collection<E>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<E>.SectionsChange) {
        sectionBatchUpdates = change as? ObservableCollection<Int>.SectionsChange
    }
}

you can try in your local, maybe just put in playground. I tried for xcode 15, it works fine with Swift 5
and for xcode 16 with swift 6, it has the error
Cast from 'ObservableCollection<E>.SectionsChange' (aka 'CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<E>>') to unrelated type 'ObservableCollection<Int>.SectionsChange' (aka 'CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<Int>>') always fails


I don't believe this should have ever compiled. Can you show a [mcve] that would compile in Swift 5.10?

right now using xcode 15, with Swift 5, the build success

This is still not a MRE. Your code as presented does not compile in Swift 5. Can you provide an example that compiles?

Hi @RobNapier are trying to build in your side, it has some dependency like class LILExpect, let me create some example code first

Hi @Sweeper, RobNapier, I add an example in my post. like me know if guys can see the error

A different approach, since you are expecting the generic type to be an Int while casting, all the generic type E should be an Int or same type.
So you can change the ObservableCollectionDelegateMock to have a generic element
class ObservableCollectionDelegateMock<Element>: ObservableCollectionDelegate {
    var rowBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange?
    var sectionBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Element>.SectionsChange?

    func collection(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange) {
        rowBatchUpdates = change
    }

    func collection(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.SectionsChange) {
        sectionBatchUpdates = change
    }
}

Associated type for protocol
public protocol ObservableCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Element
    func collection(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange)
    func collection(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.SectionsChange)
}

if you use like below, then the collection function element might not be same as associatedType
associatedtype Element
func collection<Element>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange)


it won't work, since I declare the E in the protocol I updated in above.
I also try to follow the associated Type in here, but seems associated Type if the type is used in method generic type.
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/associated-types-protocols/

@whitekevin, please check my updated answer

unfortunately it still not working
it will throw the error like this
Cannot assign value of type 'ObservableCollection.RowsChange' (aka 'CollectionChange<IndexPath, E>') to type 'CollectionChange<IndexPath, E>'
'E' previously declared here
Arguments to generic parameter 'Value' ('E' and 'E') are expected to be equal

you can try with my latest demo code, just put it in playground and try with your solution, they you will know my meaning

@whitekevin, I reproduced with the demo code no issues for me. did you try with both updated class and protocol?. If you have used like this 'func collection' in protocol, it will show error, this means you are mentioning the protocol and function generic Element is different, you should remove  in function because the protocol has one generic Element

Hi @Immanuel I posted the answer above with my code, can you tell the difference between your side.

import UIKit
import Foundation

public struct CollectionChange<Index: Hashable, Value> {}
public class ObservableArray<T> {


    // MARK: - Internal Properties

    internal(set) public var elements: [T]

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    public init<S>(elements: S) where S: Sequence, S.Element == T {
        self.elements = [T](elements)
    }

    public convenience init() {
        self.init(elements: [])
    }
}

open class ObservableCollection<Element> {
    
    public typealias RowsChange = CollectionChange<IndexPath, Element>
    public typealias SectionsChange = CollectionChange<Int, ObservableArray<Element>>
}

public protocol ObservableCollectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Element
    func collection<Element>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange)
    func collection<Element>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<E>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.SectionsChange)
}

class ObservableCollectionDelegateMock<Element>: ObservableCollectionDelegate {

    var rowBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange?
    var sectionBatchUpdates: ObservableCollection<Element>.SectionsChange?

    func collection<Element>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, rowsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.RowsChange) {
        rowBatchUpdates = change
    }

    func collection<Element>(_ collection: ObservableCollection<Element>, sectionsDidChange change: ObservableCollection<Element>.SectionsChange) {
        sectionBatchUpdates = change
    }
}

@Immanuel Here is the code I follow with your suggested, I run this with xcode 16 playground. 
it will has the error, if you don't have issue, can you share the code to me

[![error in xcode][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/IxJAGjOW.png


change all func collection to func collection. Remove  near function name

is the issue solved?

Hi @Immanuel Thanks for your help! now it works!, I also need to update the protocol be ObservableCollectionDelegate<Element>: AnyObject to make it work in the place it be set.

if you have associatedtype Element, this  is not needed near protocol name
